# Phonegap 3.1 iOS app rescales splashscreen when loading

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

When starting the app, the splashscreen image does a glitch and somehow resizes itself. This happens both locally and on phonegap build.

This is a part from my config.xml. I added the images mentioned over there:

```
enter code here
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was using "res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" in the first load instead of "res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png". So I used the same image for "res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" and it did not resize anymore..